# where should the mybatis-config.xml, the main configuer file of myBatis, be placed in?

Tags: jakarta-ee, mybatis

I am developing an application based on Spring and myBatis 3.3.1 in myEclipse 10 IDE.

My question is: where should the mybatis-config.xml, the main configuer file of myBatis, be placed in? According to official documents, it should be placed in classpath, but in myEclipse 10 where is the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of build tool you are using. If you are using **Maven/Gradle** then put it in `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: Thanks! But now, there is another question: where should the Singleton code of creating SqlSessionFactory be place in and how , in the Singleton code fragment ,should it reference the "mybatis-config.xml" configuration file?

Comment: In my way, I place the mybatis-config.xml in src/main/resources and reference it as 'String resource = "mybatis-config.xml"' in SessionFactory code, don't I?